# Kendo UI tree checkbox check and uncheck events in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treeview

I trying to find uncheck and check events for kendo ui tree with checkboxes. In the documentation it wasn't mentioned.

I could only find a check event,
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview

Please advise to implement kendo ui tree with checkboxes in angular that has check and uncheck events.

Answer (score 0):

CheckBoxes have changed events rather than check/unchecked event.

KendoUI has a "[changed](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-change)" and "[check](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-check)" event.

Here is [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IwAve) as well.